# Create many types dynamically

Tags: typescript

I currently have a relationship like this in many files, and I am looking for a way to create a combination function that allows the relationship between these to not be prone to human-error.

```
type XRaw = {};
type X = Merge<XRaw, {}>;
type XProto = Merge<X, {}>;
type XProtoPrepped = Merge<XProto, {}>;
```

Something like this:

```
type [XRaw, X, XProto, XProtoPrepped] = Build<{}, {}, {}, {}>
```

I would also like to limit the `{}` to only have the properties in the original `XRaw`, and disallow entry of unrecognized properties.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you correctly, you want something like this: type `Build<A, B, C, D> = [
    A,
    A & B,
    A & B & C,
    A & B & C & D
]
type Result = Build<{}, {}, {}, {}>
type XRaw = Result[0];
type X = Result[0];
type XProto = Result[0];
type XProtoPrepped = Result[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface Discover <Raw, RawOverrides, Proto, ProtoOverrides> {
  Raw: Raw;
  RawOverrides: Merge<Raw, RawOverrides>;
  Proto: Merge<Proto, Merge<Raw, RawOverrides>>;
  ProtoOverrides: Merge<ProtoOverrides, Merge<Proto, Merge<Raw, RawOverrides>>>;
}

type CatDiscover = Discover<{
  id: string;
}, {}, {}, {}>

type CatRaw = CatDiscover['Raw'];
type Cat = CatDiscover['RawOverrides'];
type CatProto = CatDiscover['Proto'];
type CatProtoPrepped = CatDiscover['ProtoOverrides'];
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would also like to limit the {} to only have the properties in the original XRaw, and disallow entry of unrecognized properties.

Sounds like you want `exact` types.

Sadly TypeScript doesn't support exact types yet. Here is the relevant issue raised with the TypeScript team : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936